# Alternate scenes in a QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have multiple `QGraphicsScene` objects that should be drawn into a single `QGraphicsView` at different times.

Once I've assigned a scene to a view via `setScene` member function it's possible to change the viewed scene with another?

Is it safe to assign `nullptr` via `setScene` if I don't want to show any scene or I have to pass a valid pointer each time?

**Example**

```cpp
class MyViewer : public QObject{
Q_OBJECT
  QGraphicsView sc;
  QGraphicsScene scenes[10];
  int i;
public:
  //....
  QGraphicsView *getView() { return &sc;}

  //called by a QTime event for example
  void update(){
    if(i >= 10)
      i = 0;
    sc.setScene(&(scene[i]));
    i++;
  }
};

int main(int n, const char **a){
  QApplication app(n, a);
  MyViewer vw;
  /*
   * Do some stuffs, initialize and connect a QTimer
   */
  vw.getView()->show();
  app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Based on the wording in the QGraphicsView document page, I believe the answer to all your questions is yes, but you won’t know for sure until you try it.

Comment: I think it's better to ask your question with one example. you can have one view class that has one  QGraphicsView object and one QGraphicsScene object and you assign that scene to QGraphicsView object. then you can create multiple objects from this class . and add different items to each of this classes.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I could try it, but if it's an undocumented feature then that doesn't assure me that it'll work on other platforms or with later versions of Qt library.  So my question is if that is legal in Qt regardless of actual Qt library implementation.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R So do you say to assign a different view for each scene? It sounds a bit tricky but actually I don't want to remove and add a widget each time from my main window.

Comment: @desio , i don't know what you are doing. You should explain your question with one example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's possible to change the viewed scene with another?

You can change the scene whenever you want, the documentation does not indicate a prohibition so you can do it.

### Is it safe to assign nullptr via setScene if I don't want to show any scene or I have to pass a valid pointer each time?

Qt checks if the pointer is valid and accordingly performs the actions so it is safe to pass nullptr to remove the previous scene.

---

In Qt when something is dangerous and not allowed then it will be explicitly indicated in the documentation. It is also easy to see the source code to understand the behavior.